# How to get Nokogiri to resolve XPath references when parsing XML?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, xpath

A lot has been written about Nokogiri in terms of reading XML using XPath. However, what's about using Nokogiri with XML containing XPath references.

In the example, the xml contains a XPath reference:

```
<elements>
 <element>
  <location>
   <longitude>...
   <latitude>...
  </location>
 </element>
 <element>
  <location reference="../../element/location"/>
 </element>
</elements>
```

Since both location elements are equal, only the first element is described in detail. The second just references the first.

Using Nokogiri, **xml.xpath('//location')** returns two node instances as expected. The first node contains all child nodes. The second only a reference as an attribute of the second node instance.

Ok, assuming I want to request all longitude values, I would do **xml.xpath('//location/longitude')**. This returns only one node instance. However, since there are actually two elements of type "longitude", I expected to receive two node instances, expecting Nokogiri to resolve XPath references...

How do I achieve this with Nokogiri?

Comment: I only see one longitude element in your example. Can you be more specific about the input and what you'd like to extract?

Comment: You asked this question on multiple sites, including [Nokogiri Talk](http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk). The developers monitor that list but seldom visit here, so please update your question with any answers they provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect location nodes that have actual values (non-reference nodes) and then collect all references separately, as the following snippet demonstrates:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<End
<elements>
 <element>
  <location>
   <longitude>45</longitude>
   <latitude>-70</latitude>
  </location>
 </element>
 <element>
  <location reference="../../element/location"/>
 </element>
</element>
End

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

#Collect all the explicit longitudes
longitudes = doc.search('//location[not(@reference)]/longitude').map(&:text)

#Follow references to longitudes
doc.search('//location[@reference]').each do |location|
  reference = location.attribute('reference')
  longitudes << location.xpath("#{reference}/longitude").text
end

puts longitudes #=> ["45", "45"]
```

You can build on this technique to extract whatever information you want.

Comment: I updated the example code. The reference is not an "id" but rather an XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

**You haven't provided any clue how the second `location` element references the first.**

**Even if this mechanism were known** and we were able to specify it in an XPath expression to select the referenced `location` element, the **selected two `longitude` nodes would be identical**.

When an XPath expression is evaluated it *always* returns a *set* of nodes -- that is, if the same node is selected more than once it is represented only once in the selection result -- a set doesn't contain duplicate items.

This is why, the `longitude` element will shows only once in the selection, even though it was selected twice.

**Here is an example**;

```
<a>
 <b>
   <c/>
 </b>
</a>
```

**The XPath expression**:

/a/* | //c/..

**selects only one element** `b` -- not two identical elements `b`.